# Unable to update my GitHub from my Mac

Tags: macos, git, github, terminal

Why am I unable to update my GitHub from my Mac?

`git status` produces the following:

```
On branch master Changes to be committed:   (use "git reset HEAD
<file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   file.test

Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be
committed)

    .DS_Store
```

`git push` produces the following;

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the
current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `git add .`, then `git commit -m "My commit message"`, then `git push -u origin master`.

That will set the upstream to the `origin/master`. Moving forward, just `git push` shall suffice

Comment: git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/username/FXTrader.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/FXTrader.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Do a `git pull -u origin master` first

Answer (score 1):

Git works through commits - which are basically snapshots of what your repository looked like at a given point in time. You need to commit the files to your repository before you can actually push them to GitHub.

So your first step is to add the files to the "Staging Area" with

```
git add file.text # you can do git add . but this will add all files which you may not always want
```

Now you can check the current status of the "Staging Area" with

```
git status
```

This will let you make sure that you are only committing the changes that you want added.

Now you can commit the changes. Committing will only 'save' the files that are in the Staging Area.

```
git commit -m "A useful description of what you did since your last commit"
```

Ok so now you're ready to push. Assuming you cloned from GitHub you can just run

```
git push origin master
```

But if you created this repository with `git init` you will need to tell git that you have a remote repository somewhere. Do this by running

```
git remote add https://github.com/<usernane>/<repo_name> origin
```

This origin is the name you would like to associate with the remote repository. 'Origin" is the most common but you may have other remotes like "backup" or "code_review" for different use cases.

Once you have added the remote repo, you can actually push to it with

```
git push origin master
```

Again, origin is the name for your remote repo and 'master' is a 'branch' name.

You can add the `-u` flag which will make it so that git assumes you want to push to origin. So in the future you would only need to run

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the error messages. :)

You currently have one untracked file, `.DS_Store` which I happen to know is a system file, so you may want to add that to your `.gitignore`

As for trying to push upstream, you need to set your upstream for each branch, so you simply need to type the command

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

then do a simple

```
$ git push
```

to send your changes to github.

If the branch you are pushing to online is ahead of you, then you may need to do a `git pull` to get grab the changes, before you do a `git push`.